# How do I stop Magento merging the basket on login?

Tags: magento

If you were to login to Magento and add some products to your basket and then leave the site, these are saved for the next time you return to the site.

This, however, causes an issue when you do return. If, on your return, you added a product to your basket without logging in and then logged in at the start of the checkout process, your guest and saved basket will be merged. This is undesirable.

Is there any way to make Magento clear the saved basket on login if your current basket has items in it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like the code that governs this is in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session`, specifically where it calls `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::merge`. This means that you have a few options.

1. Override the session class and force it not to cause the merge.
2. Override the quote class and cause it never to merge carts. There may be secondary bugs to this approach if other parts of the system also attempt to merge carts.
3. Hook into the event that quote calls (`sales_quote_merge_before`) and use that opportunity to empty one of the carts. You would have to detect around when this should be done, but it is by far cleaner than the other two.

Comment: Genius! I went with #3 and knocked up an observer module to clear the saved cart if the user is logging in from the checkout and there's items in the unsaved cart.

Comment: @PhilLavin I am interested in some code, if you don't mind. I've been looking up and down and then some around the code, but still can't get it right.

Comment: This one works on community, but not on enterprise, at the time of posting this - https://github.com/jacquesbh/jbh_cartmerge

Comment: @Ashfame we are seeing issues with the module from github on Magento 1.9.0.1 - did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Joseph Mastey's answer, for the event / observer, I used the describeas event, and then I removed the quote as follows:

```
 public function emptyCartUserNoLogged($observer){
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $quote = $event->getSource();

    $quote->setIsActive(false);

    $quote->delete();

 }
```

Comment: Hi. Can you do a git or show us your code briefly that can help me in one of the issue I am facing currently.

Comment: would be nice of you could share full code (mage 1.9.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I've amended the Quote.php (/Sales/Model/) on line 1344 within the merge function the following.

```
foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $this->removeItem($item->getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Magento extension that prevents the carts from being merged:
https://github.com/jacquesbh/jbh_cartmerge

It makes use of the `sales_quote_merge_before` event where it removes the quote items of the customer's cart.